# How to put custom messages into a file in PHP

Tags: php, logging

I am sending some messages to the server through my `php` file. I need to have a file record of what is passed with a time stamp through my `php` for later references and bug fixes. I used following code but nothing changed in my file. What would be the issue if I use `wamp` server in my local machine? I have attached my sample code here!any guide on correct way to achieve this is what i am little new to php.

```
    <?PHP
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600');
    //include files--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    include_once("config.php");



    //functions set class----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class converter
    {
        //Log file------------------------------
        const GENERAL_LOG_DIR = '/log.txt';

        function logmsg($msg,$num)
        {
            $date = date('d.m.Y h:i:s');
            $log = $msg."   |  Date:  ".$date."\n";
            error_log($msg."   |  message:  ".$date.$num, 3, self::GENERAL_LOG_DIR);
        }



    }

    $message2="some text";
    $num=11;


    $obj=new converter;
        set_time_limit(0);
        /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

        if($socket)
        echo "<br>Successfully socket created<br>";
        else
        echo "<br>Cannot create socket<br>";

        $connect=socket_connect($socket,$svraddress,$port);
        if($connect)
        echo "<br>Successfully connected to server<br>";
        else
        echo "<br>Cannot connect to server<br>";



        $write=socket_write($socket,$message2);
        $obj->logmsg($message2,$num);
        echo '<h3 style="color:red">'.$message2."</h3></br>";
        echo ' send on '.date("y:m:d:h:i:s").'</br>';


    echo "Closing socket...";
    socket_close($socket);
    echo "finished.<br /><br />";
    echo "{\"success\": true, \"message\": \"OK\"}";

    ?>
```

Comment: You want to write logs in to a file in your server?

Comment: yeah i am creating a simulator which sends data to another server(web service) i need to check data i sent from here and data received there! then i can understand if any error occurs easily and from which side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did these using following methods i got my work done still don't know what happened in previous case.still new to php so hope this would help anyone who has the same issue

### method1

```
$file = fopen("text.log","a");
    echo fwrite($file,$msg."\n");
    fclose($file);
```

### method2

```
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $msg;
$current.="\n"; */
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents('text.log', $current . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```